# How to change the height and width of image when exporting from Tableau Server

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell to export images from Tableau server to C:

I have managed to export the image, but when changing the height and width it has no effect. I change the Height and width to 100 it still doesn't change.

part of code here..

```
.\tabcmd export "CityReports/Germany?Tier=$Tier1&Reports%20Period%20(To)=$ReportingPeriodTo" --png -width 10 --height 10 -f "C:\BarChart_$Tier.png"
```

Comment: `-width` -> `--width`?

Comment: yes i've tried that. still no luck

Comment: Then you need to provide more information. Does it work when you invoke from `cmd.exe` (adjusting the variable reference)? If it doesn't work there either, your problem is unrelated to PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters `--width` and `--height` work only when your dashboard is published with **Size** set to **Automatic** or **Range**. They don't work with **Fixed size**. So try to republishing it with Tableau Desktop, but before set on your dashboard non-fixed size.